# Java: Rotate a Point around an other using Google Maps Coordinates

Tags: java, google-maps, rotation, coordinates, point

From Google Earth I got a Box with coordinates for a picture, like following:

```
    <LatLonBox>
        <north>53.10685</north>
        <south>53.10637222222223</south>
        <east>8.853144444444444</east>
        <west>8.851858333333333</west>
        <rotation>-26.3448</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
```

Now I want to test weather a point intersect with this LatLonBox.
My base idea to check, whether a point intersect with the LatLonBox was, to rotate the point back by the given angle, and then to test whether the point intersect with a regular (not rotated) rectangle.

I tried to calculate the rotation manually:

```
public static MyGeoPoint rotatePoint(MyGeoPoint point, MyGeoPoint origion, double degree)
{
double x = origion.getLatitude() + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (point.getLatitude() - origion.getLatitude()) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (point.getLongitude() - origion.getLongitude()));
double y =  origion.getLongitude()  + (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (point.getLatitude() - origion.getLatitude()) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree))  * (point.getLongitude() - origion.getLongitude()));

return new MyGeoPoint(x, y);
```

}

```
public boolean intersect(MyGeoPoint geoPoint)
{   
    geoPoint = MyGeoPoint.rotatePoint(geoPoint, this.getCenter(), - this.getRotation());
    
    return (geoPoint.getLatitude() < getTopLeftLatitude()
            && geoPoint.getLatitude() > getBottomRightLatitude()
                && geoPoint.getLongitude() > getTopLeftLongitude()
                    && geoPoint.getLongitude() < getBottomRightLongitude());
}
```

And it seems that the results are wrong.

```
    LatLonBox box = new LatLonBox(53.10685, 8.851858333333333, 53.10637222222223, 8.853144444444444, -26.3448);
    
    MyGeoPoint point1 = new MyGeoPoint(53.106872, 8.852311);
    MyGeoPoint point2 = new MyGeoPoint(53.10670378322918, 8.852967186822669);   
    MyGeoPoint point3 = new MyGeoPoint(53.10652664993972, 8.851994565566875);
    MyGeoPoint point4 = new MyGeoPoint(53.10631650700605, 8.85270995172055);
    
    System.out.println(box.intersect(point1));
    System.out.println(box.intersect(point2));
    System.out.println(box.intersect(point3));
    System.out.println(box.intersect(point4));
```

The result is true, false, false, true. But it should be 4x true.
Probably I´, making some kind of error in reasoning.
Maybe because the latitude values are getting bigger upwards. But I don´t knwo how to change the formular.

I need some help ...

---

EDIT:
I think my basic idea and formular is right. Also I found similar solutions eg. [link](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/checking-if-point-inside-rotated-rectangle) and couldn´t find any difference.

So I think the only possible error source is, that the axis are not proportional. So the problem is how to take account of this.

I hope someone has got an idea.

Comment: Probably the zero angle direction differs?

Comment: Anyway, what would you like to have?

Comment: Hm I don´t think that´s the reason.
My base idea to check, wheather a point intersect with the LatLonBox was, to rotate the point back by the given angle, and then to test whether the point intersect with a regular rectangle.

Comment: Can you just test with simple region like (0,0,10,10) and rotation angle of 45 degrees? I am not familar with google maps api, and can't say what the rotation means, what is center point and what is zero rotation but generally it should be simple. Is the class `LatLonBox` yours?

Comment: I thought that the rotation means that the specified rectangle is rotated by x degrees arount the center. And yes the class LatLonBox is mine. I have all mentioned values from google maps, so I know that the result has to be 4x true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was indeed that the axis were not proportional.

The following method takes care of it.

```
public static MyGeoPoint rotatePoint(MyGeoPoint point, MyGeoPoint origion, double degree)
{
double x =  origion.longitude   + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (point.longitude - origion.longitude) - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree))  * (point.latitude - origion.latitude) / Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(origion.latitude)));
double y = origion.latitude + (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree)) * (point.longitude - origion.longitude) * Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(origion.latitude))) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree))   * (point.latitude - origion.latitude));
return new MyGeoPoint(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to check if these four points are in rotated rectangle.

I would recommend checking not by corner points because your rectangle is rotated but:

if you have rotated rectangle ABCD then calculate lines |AB|, |BC|,|CD| and |DA|. If you have two points then use y=ax+b (you will calculate a,b by by giving [x,y] of both coordinates that gives you two easy equatations).

Finally function intersect will check

```
  if point <= line |CD| 
      AND point >= line |AB|
          AND point <= line |BC|
             AND point >= |DA|
```

then it is inside rect.

This can be done when your point P[x,y] you put in ax+y+b (a>0 or -ax-y-b). If  it is zero it is lying on the line, if it is < than it is under line or "on the left side". Hope I helped..

BTW why are you using -degree value, which you multiply by -1 , is it necessary?

Comment: I multiplied with -1 so that the function rotates clockwise and I´m useing -degree value to rotate the point back.

Comment: I can´t see an advantage by this approach. I would even have to roatete all four corners of the rectangle to get the rotated rectangle and to calculate the lines. So my problem the rotation stays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the data structure `LatLonBox` doesn't make any sense as a description for the boundary of a picture.  A box in lat-lon coordinates is *not* a geometric rectangle. (Think about a box near or including the north pole.)  You need to re-think your application to deal in a lat/lon coordinate for the *center* of the picture and then deal with the rotation as an angle with respect to lines of latitude (parallel to the equator).  (Even then, a picture with center on the north or south pole will be a degenerate case that must be handled separately.)  So a box should properly be something like:

```
<geobox>
  <center_lat>41</center_lat>
  <center_lon>-74</center_lon>
  <rotation_degrees_ccw>-23</rotation_degrees_ccw>
  <width>1000</width> <!-- in pixels or meters, but not in degrees! -->
  <height>600</height> <!-- same as above -->
</geobox>
```

Having said all that, suppose you have a true geometric box centered at (x0,y0), width w, height h, rotated angle T about its *center*.  Then you can test a point P(x,y) for membership in the box with the following.  You need the transformation that takes the box to the origin and aligns it with the axes.  This is Translate(-x0,-y0) then Rotate(-T).  This transformation as a matrix is

```
[cos(-T) -sin(-T) 0][1 0 -x0]   [ cos(T)  sin(T) -x0*cos(T)-y0*sin(T)]
[sin(-T)  cos(-T) 0][0 1 -y0] = [-sin(T)  cos(T)  x0*sin(T)-y0*cos(T)]
[0        0       1][0 0   1]   [  0        0                  1     ]
```

You want to apply this transformation to the point to be tested and then see if it lies in the desired box:

```
// Transform the point to be tested.
ct = cos(T);
st = sin(T);
xp =  ct * x + st * y - x0 * ct - y0 * st;
yp = -st * x + ct * y + x0 * st - y0 * ct;
// Test for membership in the box.
boolean inside = xp >= -w/2 && xp <= w/2 && yp >= -h/2 && yp <= h/2;
```

It's late and I haven't checked this arithmetic, but it's close.  Say if it doesn't work.

Comment: I can´t change the structure of LatLonBox. I get it exactly as it is from Google Earth.

Comment: Then what is the definition of a LatLonBox?  How does a rectangular picture fit in a shape that's not a rectangle?